# How do I concatenate arbitrary files in a folder using brunch?

Tags: brunch

I have a bunch of arbitrary text files in my project in a directory which I need to concatenate into a single text file. The order of concatenation isn't important. Is it possible to do this using brunch?

Comment: Never heard of brunch but the word "join" led me to believe it was something to do with SQL. Hope this edit helps you find an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve with a `after-brunch` plugin (execute a shell command line `cat app/file-{1,2,3}.txt > public/result.txt`).

Comment: My use case is this. I have a bunch of jade partials in a directory, I want to create a single jade file by concatenating them all. I want to use another plugin to convert this big jade file into static HTML. So how would I make sure that my after-brunch plugin would run first so that the input for the jade plugin is available by the time it runs ?

Comment: Take a look at `static-jade-brunch` plugin.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this done with the plugin you mentioned. It would be nice if this feature was built into brunch which would allow me to create files by concatenating a set of files using an anymatch set, nothing tied to jade or any other format.

Comment: I was able to get this done using "before-brunch" plugin ( I wanted concatenation to happen before brunch compilation started ) .